# BeautifulSoup not showing tag's attributes value

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to get the value from data-initial-value in the next tag from an HTML:

<input type="text" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="username" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Nombre de usuario" name="Username" id="username" ***data-initial-value="mujicapedro661"*** badinput="false" aria-invalid="false" dir="ltr">

But when I try this:

```
gmailHtml = requests.get("URL")
gmailSoup = BeautifulSoup(gmailHtml.content, "html.parser")
gmailSoup.find("div", {"class": "Xb9hP"})
input_tag = gmailSoup.find_all("input")
for data_tag in input_tag:
    data_tag["data-initial-value"]
    print(data_tag)
```

I get the attribute empty:

```
<input /IRRELEVANT TAGS/ data-initial-value="" /MORE IRRELEVANT TAGS/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')
for input_tag in soup.find_all('input'):
    print(input_tag['data-initial-value'])
```

Output : mujicapedro661